# ReactXP: "'length' is missing in type" for array of interface

Tags: reactjs, reactxp

I am using ReactXP (which uses TypeScript) to code a chat client that displays a single panel that contains a stack of messages in the top part and a form at the bottom in which to submit new chat messages. I am trying to break the stack of messages into an array of objects of `ChatMessage` type. This particular example uses the ReactXP extension for VirtualListView.

When I try to compile the example below, I receive the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ messages: ChatMessage[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChatMessage[]'.
   Property 'length' is missing in type '{ messages: ChatMessage[]; }
```

I can see from the error message that `ChatMessage[]` is not being interpreted as an array because it lacks a `'length`' property, which would be expected for an array.

**How do I cast `ChatMessage[]` properly so that `ChatMessageStackView` calls `render()` without error? Why does `messages` become a nested object when I reference `this.props.stack`?**

Here is the example:

```
import RX = require('reactxp');
import { VirtualListView, VirtualListViewItemInfo } from 'reactxp-virtuallistview';

export interface ChatMessage extends VirtualListViewItemInfo {
    content: string,
    username: string,
    timestamp: string 
}

interface ChatMessageStackProps {
    stack: ChatMessage[];
}

export const ChatMessageStack = (messages:ChatMessage[]) =>
    (
        <VirtualListView
            itemList={messages}
            renderItem={renderMessage}
            animateChanges={ true }
            skipRenderIfItemUnchanged={ true }
        />
    )

function renderMessage(message:ChatMessage, hasFocus?: boolean) {
    return (
        <RX.View>
            <RX.Text>
                {message.timestamp} {message.username} {message.content}
            </RX.Text>
        </RX.View>
    )
}

export class ChatMessageStackView extends RX.Component<ChatMessageStackProps, RX.Stateless> {
    constructor(props:ChatMessageStackProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ChatMessageStack messages={this.props.stack}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type signature is incorrect in `ChatMessageStack`.

The argument is actually `props`, but you are trying to get `messages`.

If you look closer at the error message, it actually explains it well.
It's not trying to get `length` of `messages`, it's trying to do it on the object, like so `{ messages: ChatMessage[]; }.length`. The object is `props` in this case.

Either use `props.messages` or change the type signature to:

```
export const ChatMessageStack = ({ messages } { messages: ChatMessage[] }) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set this ChatMessage[] like:
ChatMessage:any[]

Comment: But `ChatMessage` is already an interface. I'm not sure how to make the proposed changed because `ChatMessage` is not of type `any[]`.